# What do I do with these roselle plants?

Tags: diagnosis, containers, repotting

[image]

Due to other work, I was unable to transplant these roselle plants to smaller containers. Their roots grew tangled and the leaves were very sparse and discoloured/reddish tipped. Though these bore one roselle each on the top. I have harvested them. Now I have two three 6 inch clay pots. Do I plant these in bunches in those? Or do I plant one each? Some of them have immature buds. Are those better or the harvested ones better for planting?

Answer (score 1):

I've never grown roselle, but I understand it's related to okra, which I have grown.

I would recommend putting each plant in its own container, especially as they've already been separated. There's not much reason to keep them together, in my opinion.